# Prime faces,jogar os dados de uma dataTable para uma dialog

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, aplicação-web

contato tela

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<p:growl autoUpdate="true"/> 

    <p:panel header="Formulário" id="panel">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Nome"></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText value="#{ContatoControl.contato.nome }"></p:inputText>
            <h:outputText value="Telefone"></h:outputText>
            <p:inputMask value="#{ContatoControl.contato.telefone }"
                mask="(99) 9999-9999"></p:inputMask>
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{ContatoControl.confirmar }"
                value="Confirmar" update="contatos, panel" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>

    <p:dataTable id="contatos" value="#{ContatoControl.contatos }"
        rows="10" var="cont" width="100%" emptyMessage="Sem registros"
        editable="true">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputLabel value="Tabela de Contatos: " />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <p:outputLabel value="Consultar: " />
            <p:inputText id="pesquisar" value="#{ContatoControl.nomeOuTelefone}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Pesquisar" update="contatos"
                actionListener="#{ContatoControl.pesquisar}" />


        </f:facet>
        <p:column sortBy="#{cont.id }">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Id"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{cont.id }"></h:outputText>
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{cont.nome }">

            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{cont.nome }"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>

                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{cont.nome }"></p:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>

        </p:column>
         <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{ContatoControl.modificar(cont)}" update="contatos"/>
        <p:column sortBy="#{cont.telefone }">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Telefone"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{cont.telefone }"></h:outputText>

        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Ação">

            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" id="btnEditarProduto"
                actionListener="#{ContatoControl.selecionarContatoParaEdicao(cont)}"
                onclick="PF('dialogNovoContato').show();" />
```

> ```
>           <p:commandButton value="PopUp"
>               actionListener="#{ContatoControl.selecionarContatoParaEdicao(cont)}"
>               onclick="PF(alterarpop).show()" />
> ```

```
            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{ContatoControl.excluir(cont)}"
                icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" update="contatos" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>



</ui:define>
```

controler

`

```
package br.com.ambientinformatica.primefaces.controle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import br.com.ambientinformatica.ambientjsf.util.UtilFaces;
import br.com.ambientinformatica.jpa.exception.PersistenciaException;
import br.com.ambientinformatica.primefaces.entidade.Contato;
import br.com.ambientinformatica.primefaces.persistencia.ContatoDao;

@Controller("ContatoControl")
@Scope("conversation")
public class ContatoControl {

    private String nomeOuTelefone;


    private Contato contato = new Contato();

    @Autowired
    private ContatoDao contatoDao;

    private List<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<Contato>();

    private boolean editMode;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listar(null);
    }

    public void confirmar(ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            contatoDao.alterar(contato);
            listar(evt);
            contato = new Contato();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UtilFaces.addMensagemFaces(e);
        }
    }

    public void listar(ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            contatos = contatoDao.listar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UtilFaces.addMensagemFaces(e);
        }
    }

    public void pesquisar() {
        contatos = contatoDao.listarPorNomeOuTelefone(nomeOuTelefone);
    }

    public void excluir(Contato contato) {
        try {
            contatoDao.excluirPorId(contato.getId());
            contatos = contatoDao.listar();
            UtilFaces.addMensagemFaces("Contato Excluído com sucesso!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            UtilFaces.addMensagemFaces(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

public void selecionarContatoParaEdicao(Contato  contato){

        try {
            this.contato = contatoDao.consultar(contato.getId());
        } catch (PersistenciaException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    // Metodo para alterar o contato//
    // public void alterar(Contato contato) throws PersistenciaException {
    // contatoDao.alterar(contato);
    // }

    public void update() {
        this.editMode = true;
    }
    /// teste para ver se altera pelo table esta funcionando
    public void modificar(Contato com) throws PersistenciaException{
    contatoDao.alterar(com);

    }

    public void listarTodos() throws PersistenciaException {
        contatos = contatoDao.listar();
    }

    public Contato getContato() {
        return contato;
    }

    public void setContato(Contato contato) {
        this.contato = contato;
    }

    public List<Contato> getContatos() {
        return contatos;
    }

    public String getNomeOuTelefone() {
        return nomeOuTelefone;
    }

    public void setNomeOuTelefone(String nomeOuTelefone) {
        this.nomeOuTelefone = nomeOuTelefone;
    }

    public boolean isEditMode() {
        return editMode;
    }

    public void setEditMode(boolean editMode) {
        this.editMode = editMode;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((contato == null) ? 0 : contato.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((contatoDao == null) ? 0 : contatoDao.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((contatos == null) ? 0 : contatos.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nomeOuTelefone == null) ? 0 : nomeOuTelefone.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ContatoControl other = (ContatoControl) obj;
        if (contato == null) {
            if (other.contato != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!contato.equals(other.contato))
            return false;
        if (contatoDao == null) {
            if (other.contatoDao != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!contatoDao.equals(other.contatoDao))
            return false;
        if (contatos == null) {
            if (other.contatos != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!contatos.equals(other.contatos))
            return false;
        if (nomeOuTelefone == null) {
            if (other.nomeOuTelefone != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nomeOuTelefone.equals(other.nomeOuTelefone))
            return false;
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ContatoControl [nomeOuTelefone=" + nomeOuTelefone + ", contato=" + contato + ", contatoDao="
                + contatoDao + ", contatos=" + contatos + "]";
    }

}
```

`

contato class

`

```
package br.com.ambientinformatica.primefaces.entidade;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class Contato {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator="contato_seq", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   @SequenceGenerator(name="contato_seq", sequenceName="contato_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
   private Integer id;

   private String nome;

   private String telefone;

   public String getNome() {
      return nome;
   }

   public void setNome(String nome) {
      this.nome = nome;
   }

   public String getTelefone() {
      return telefone;
   }

   public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
      this.telefone = telefone;
   }

   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }


}
```

`

No bloco de codigo destacado e onde tenho o botao para fazer a ação,quando eu tiro o "PF" antes do alterarpop ,a dialog abre,mas quando ele esta ai ela não abre,preciso que abra a dialog com os dados da linha preenchendo os campos para editar e salvar.
quem puder me ajudar,muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa.

Aqui tem um bom exemplo: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml, é só você dar uma olhada no código que você vai entender, é bem simples. De forma resumida, pude notar que você não usa `<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{value}" target="#{ContatoControl.selectedValue}" /> (exemplo)` no seu actionButton. Isso é necessário para que você possa definir o valor que será enviado ao elemento após a ação de click (nesse caso), para que esse mesmo valor possa ser recuperado depois: `<p:dialog widgetVar="alterarpop" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">`. Dentro do `dialog` você usaria o `#{ContatoControl.selectedValue}`. 
Obs.: ao usar `PF(alterarpop).show()` o que vai na invocação do dialog precisa estar entre '', nesse caso 'alterarpop'.

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!!